# Проблема с повышением targetSdkVersion до 28 версии

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle, sdk

Решил внести маленькие правки в приложение и play market теперь требует использовать SDK не менее 28 версии. При простой смене targetSdkVersion до 28, перестает отображаться серверная часть приложения (заставки для телефона) само приложение запускается нормально.

Ниже приложил build gradle который используется когда все работает. Може нужно повысить версии конкретных бибдиоте или еще, что?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.setUseSupportLibrary(true)
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.APP.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 27
        versionName "2.1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.1'
    compile 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.leo.simplearcloader:simplearcloader:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:v1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:animated-svg-view:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Покупал год назад исходный код на codecanyon, сейчас разработчик не доступен

Comment: кроме того что в targetSdk повысили, вы библиотеки тоже обновили?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko  пробовал  http://prntscr.com/qbctpe повышать данные  и другие библиотеки до последних версий, не помогало.

Comment: С таким количеством библиотек и опытному программисту обновиться не "раз плюнуть". Как минимум нужно повысить все support и google - это может потребовать изменений в коде, а так же обновления остальных библиотек, которые зависят от обновлённых, и снова изменений в коде. Сами библиотеки `support` уже устарели и, возможно, лучше сразу заменить их на `AndroidX` - в свежей версии студии это можно сделать через `Menu->Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX`. В любом случае придётся исправлять ошибки, чтобы проект довести до рабочего состояния. Не забудьте про резервную копию, прежде чем ковыряться.

Comment: @woesss, дело говорит, но использовать автоматический переход это не самое верное решение. У меня на двух небольших проектах было так что первый раз перешло без проблем, то во втором проекте это привело к таким ошибкам которые было достаточно долго и сложно отследить. Попробуйте конечно, вдруг вам повезёт! В ручную сделать это относительно не сложно, но нужно будет найти все связанные библиотеки и заменить импорты из данного напрвления, не забудьте про разметку(это важно!). Второе: я бы начал именно с этого, а после фикса всех ошибок перешол бы к обновлению всех библиотек.

Comment: P.S. Только что подумал о том, смог бы я это сделать когда только начинал? Наверное нет. Наверное легче найти того кто это сделает. Если это средне сложный проект это займёт от 4-8, ну а вхудшем случае - если проект достаточно старый до 16 часов. и умножте на рейт: $15-20/час - будет и дешевле и быстрее, если это прибыльный проект.

Comment: @Valeriy конкретно этот не прибыльный, но и забрасывать не хотелось бы. А обойти проверку SDK и перезалить приложение с SDK 27 сейчас совсем нереально ?

Comment: Не знаю, такого проделывать никогда не приходилось. Если гугля требует, значит на то есть причины... Тогда вам стоит садиться изучать android. Есть второй вариант, есть множество фри-ланс бирж, где очень сложно стартонуть без отзывов, потому многие делают работу за копейки (или даже за только оплату пронцентов сделки) и отзыв. Особенно на забугорных, мне знакомы Freelancer и UpWork, сам когда-то так искал проект, не нашел - работаю в компании... Поищите там, мб кого найдёте, только будьте аккуратны, есть сложные формы тупости и самоуверенности.

Comment: Ещё ворос, что подразумевается под: не отображается серверная часть? Что делает ваше приложение и зачем ему серверная часть? Я вижу у вас есть Firebase и Facebook, второе испльзуется для входа? А в файрбесе есть ads, у вас перестала отображаться реклама?

Comment: @Valeriy   приложение просто заставки для мобильных.  Когда компилируется приложение на SDK 28 не подгружаются лента картинок (приложение открывается). Facebook да для входа.    Мне просто интереснее изучать раскрутку приложений, чем сам коддинг.

Comment: Не могу сказать что у вас что-то явно не рабочее должно быть. Не понятно, доходят у вас данные до вас или нет. Если нет, можно попробовать обновить эти библиотеки, но лучше конечно сделать полный апгрейд: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'.  А ещё лучше, начните с изучения логов, соберите дебажную версию и поссмотрите логи, приходят ли вам данные из бека

Comment: @Valeriy  спасибо!